# Simple link list program in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

Simple code of Link List implementation in C .
Is it correct way to write or I am missing anything ? Is free section is ok?

```
typedef struct box{// data type definition 
        int data;
        struct box* next;
    } node; // "node"

node* node1 = (node *)malloc( sizeof(node));// heap memory allocation for node1
    if(node1 != NULL){ // ( safety check)
        node1->data = 1;//assign value
        node1->next = NULL;// doesn't point to anyone
    }

node* node2 =(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));// node 2 work
    if(node2 != NULL) {
        node2 ->data = 2;
        node2->next = NULL;
    }

node1->next = node2;//first connection
node2->next = NULL;//second connection

for(node *tmp =node1; tmp !=NULL; tmp=tmp->next){// printing value in nodes using *tmp pointer
        printf("%i\n",tmp->data );
    }

free(node1);//delete node1 allocation on heap
free(node2);//delete node 2 allocation on heap
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. There are no functions, no includes. Just a bunch if declarations and C statements. The statements look more or less correct. Isuggest you write a full program and see by yourself if it works.

Comment: Your "safety checks" are pointless. Consider what actualy happens if `node1` is NULL.

Comment: @HIMANSHU NARAYAN The variable node is not used.

Comment: Thanks for comment sir, above code works under main( ) function . "safety check" - If node1 is not null , then it will not assign node data value like 1,2.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  I used temp variable pointer to iterate over all node. Is any error , please write.

Comment: What is the actual *question* ? *"Is it correct way to write or I am missing anything ?"* suggests you're asking us to 'review' your work? Does your code *work*? if so, [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for this. If *not*, then please specify the *exact* nature of your problem [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71361180/edit) and include a *proper* [mcve].

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Should I also include free(temp)( temporary pointer)  at end or is it ok?If you find  error in code , please comment

Comment: @HIMANSHUNARAYAN If several pointers point to the same dynamically allocated memory then to free it you need to call the function free only once using any of the pointers. That is you do not free pointers. You have to free dynamically allocated memory using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration

```
struct box{// data type definition 
    int data;
    struct box* next;
} node; // "node"
```

you declared the variable `node` of the type `struct box` that is not further used.

It seems you mean a typedef declaration like

```
typedef struct box{// data type definition 
    int data;
    struct box* next;
} node; // "node"
```

As a result these statements

```
node* node1 = (node *)malloc( sizeof(node));
node* node2 =(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

shall produce compilation errors.

If your list is supposed to contain for example 100 nodes will you declare 100 variables node1 ,..., node100?

You need to write a separate function that includes new nodes in the list.

These statements

```
node1->next = node2;//first connection
node2->next = NULL;//second connection
```

can invoke undefined behavior if either pointer is equal to NULL.